# Delete object with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to delete an object in my Parse Cloud with Swift Langage.
But I can't do it. There is my code :

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Activity")
    query.whereKey("activityID", equalTo: self.activityId)
         query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objectFo: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil && objectFo != nil {
                    objectFo?.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if (success) {
                            println("success")
                        } else {
                            println(error)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    println(error)
                }
            }
```

"Success" appear in my console, but my object isn't deleted..
With Objective-C it's ok, but in Swift...

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really get an object for your query? Are there results?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Activity")
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(self.activityId) {
    (activity: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && activity!= nil {
            println(activity)
            activity.deleteInBackground()
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
}
```

Check: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-deleting-objects and https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-retrieving-objects once more.